# Get Worksheet with Microsoft Graph API using Managed Identity of Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

This might be a simple question but I am not entirely sure how to interpret the Microsoft documentation on the Graph REST API.

Specifically, the **Get Worksheet** operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

It states Permission type **Application** with 'Least privileged permissions' **Not supported**. Does this mean I cannot use this API call when invoking it using the managed identity of an Azure Function?

If not, what would be an alternative approach to read the content of an Excel file stored on MS Teams using the managed identity of an Azure Function?

Answer (score 1):

I've very similar case. Managed identity in Azure Function to access excel files on SharePoint/OneDrive and I'm using [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi) NuGet to read/write excel file.

Example:

```
using var fileStream = await client.Drives[{drive_id}].Root.ItemWithPath($"{folder}/{filename}").Content.GetAsync();
// read content
using var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileStream);

var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
sheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(1).SetCellValue("Hello");

using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
// write to a new stream
workbook.Write(outputStream, true);
outputStream.Position = 0;
// upload
var driveItem = await client.Drives[{drive_id}].Root.ItemWithPath($"{folder}/{newFileName}").Content.PutAsync(outputStream);
```

Comment: Interesting! I will have a look at this library. Next to that I'm also looking into an alternative for using MS Teams and see if we can simply use SFTP and blob containers to get the Excel files we need.